# Can I search all artists with "✚" on their name on SoundCloud?

Tags: search, soundcloud

Can I search all artists with "✚" on their name on SoundCloud?

I was trying to find ✚ C H V K S ✚ or something.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to search using one of the aliases/entities for 'heavy greek cross'.

See here: http://graphemica.com/%E2%9C%9A

For Sound Cloud, use the URL escape code: `%E2%9C%9A`

Example: https://soundcloud.com/search?q=%E2%9C%9A

If you type into the search box, Sound Cloud will add '25'.

Example: `q=%25E2%259C%259A`

So you must remove the '25''s from the URL.